# How to make world spawn point

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have an area that when my sister and my dad join, they spawn on that exact spot. Are there any commands that allow me to do that?

Comment: Using the command: `/setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>` will roughly set the default spawn point to the coordinates you entered. This will not overwrite your spawn point if you have an existing bed etc.

Comment: I suppose this is a Vanilla server?

Answer (score 0):

```
/setworldspawn X Y Z
```

(or just

```
/setworldspawn
```

while standing at the desired coordinates) will set the world spawn to the position specified.

Players will spawn at a random location in a 20x20 area centered on that spot, on top of the highest solid block. You can change the size of the area using

```
/gamerule spawnRadius R
```

`10` is the default, and `0` will cause them to spawn on the exact X and Z coordinates specified.

Players will still spawn on top of the highest solid block at their X and Z. So, if the world spawn is inside of a house, they will spawn on the roof.